# Unable to make value fields editable after clicking on a link button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, detailsview

I've created a link button and made a event handler for it. But still unable to make the values editable.

This is the link button:

```
<FooterTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" OnClick="lbEdit_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
</FooterTemplate>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
protected void lbEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dvEAEdit.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you get an errors?

Comment: No, no errors... When I click on the link button the page refreshes thats it.